# In React why does calling a function from another function in our code not work and display?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a question about React and JSX.

The main component code below works correctly:

```
function App(){
    return (
        <Hello />
    )

}
```

Then I define a function component and call a function inside it.
Why does it not work?

```
function Hello(){
    f();    
}

function f(){
    return(<h1>hello</h1>);
}
```

Whereas this does work:

```
 function Hello(){
      return(<h1>hello</h1>);
 }
```

Comment: first of all always wrap your jsx elements within either <div> or any other suitable tag

Answer (score 4):

## Functional Components must return React Components of some form

To elaborate on other answers, you should [refer to the example in the React docs:](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)

```
    function Welcome(props) {
      return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
    }
```

> This function is a valid React component because it accepts a single “props” (which stands for properties) object argument with data and **returns a React element**.

So, as others have said, your best bet is to **return** a React element (via [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html), presumably, but can call other components as you're trying):

```
// Using conventional function syntax
function Hello(){
    return f();    
}

// Using arrow functions and implicit returns
const Hello = () => f();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
function Hello(){
    f();    
}
```

to

```
function Hello(){
    return f();    
}
```

Without the return keyword, `Hello()`'s return value is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return from the function as

```
function Hello(){
 return f();    
}
```

or

```
const Hello = () => f(); // implicit return
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think that in the `Hello` you have to add a `return`. Remember that the default behaviour of a function is to `return` **undefined**

```
function Hello(){
    return f();    
}

function f(){
    return(<h1>hello</h1>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from the Hello component.  You are calling the function f() but not doing anything useful with it.  To make the function do something more useful you can do:

```
function Hello(){
    return f();    
}
```